# Hot swapping a mirrored disk on a HP UX

Tags: lvm, software-raid, hp-ux

I'm trying to do a hot swap on a mirrored lvm.

```
$ vgdisplay -v /dev/vg00

   --- Physical volumes ---
PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2
PV Status                   unavailable
Total PE                    4318
Free PE                     845
Autoswitch                  On
Proactive Polling           Off

PV Name                     /dev/dsk/c2t1d0s2
PV Status                   available
Total PE                    4318
Free PE                     845
Autoswitch                  On
Proactive Polling           Off
```

After swapping disks I run an ioscan to find the new device and then do a insf. I know it's the new disk because it shows as a HP instead of a Seagate.

```
$ ioscan -C disks

disk      1  0/1/1/0.0.0     sdisk      CLAIMED     DEVICE       HP 36.4GMAP3367NC
                        /dev/dsk/c2t0d0     /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2   /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0
                        /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2  /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s1   /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s3  
                        /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s1  /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s3

disk      2  0/1/1/0.1.0     sdisk      CLAIMED     DEVICE       SEAGATE ST373307LC
                        /dev/dsk/c2t1d0     /dev/dsk/c2t1d0s2   /dev/rdsk/c2t1d0    
                        /dev/rdsk/c2t1d0s2  /dev/dsk/c2t1d0s1   /dev/dsk/c2t1d0s3   
                        /dev/rdsk/c2t1d0s1  /dev/rdsk/c2t1d0s3
```

So far it's going good. Then I hit my first snag.

```
$ vgcfgrestore -n /dev/vg00 /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2

vgcfgrestore: Could not open Physical Volume "/dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2".
```

Maybe I needed to reduce the volume group first.

```
$ vgreduce /dev/vg00 /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2

vgreduce: Physical volume "/dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2" could not be removed since some of its
physical extents are still in use.
```

How can some of the physical extents be in use? I pulled the old drive.

So then I thought maybe I need to create a physical volume first.

```
$ pvcreate -f -B /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2

pvcreate: Couldn't open physical volume "/dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2":
I/O error
```

I can't create a pv from that partition of the drive but it'll let me from the main partition.

```
$ pvcreate -f -B /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0
Physical volume "/dev/rdsk/c2t0d0" has been successfully created.
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing. Why is the new disk still showing c2t0d0s1,c2t0d0s2, and c2t0d0s3? Why can't I do a pvcreate on c2t0d0s2? Why can't I do a 'vgcfgrestore' or a 'vgreduce'?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to deactivate the physical volume:

```
# pvchange -a n /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2
```

After that,

```
# vgcfgrestore -n /dev/vg00 /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s2
```

```
# pvchange -a y /dev/dsk/c2t0d0s2
```

Don't do the pvcreate on the whole disk, that will screw up the disk layout.

Comment: I needed to to an idisk to format the system partitions. That's what I was missing. Then after doing a `pvchange -a n` I was off to the races.

Comment: Yes, sure, you have to make the partitions with idisk before . Sorry for not mentioning it.